# CSS position div over background image responsive

Tags: css, html, response

I need to have a image on div background. Over this image, its mandatory to have one title, subtitle and a button.

All these three elements need to have top and left in % for dynamic position.

I had made several tries, but without success.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="title">LIAM</div>
        <div id="subtitle">SUPER SLIM FIT</div>
        <div id="link">
            <a href="#"> See all jeans</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
  #block1 {
    background-image: url('http://tiffosi.com/fw16/img/img1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1450px;
    max-width: 1086px;
    max-height: 1450px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#block1 #subtitle {
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23.4%;
    left: 43.5%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#block1 #link {
    width: 184px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 43px;
    line-height: 43px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 11pt;
    top: 29.3%;
    left: 41.3%;
    position: absolute;
}

#block1 #link a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    #block1 #title{
        top: 12%;
        left:42%;
        font-size:80%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    #block1 #title {
        font-size: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 16.5%;
        left: 42%;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
}

#block1 #title {
    font-size: 97px;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16.5%;
    left: 42%;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Link to jsffidle: https://jsfiddle.net/jggscada/

Comment: Please format your CSS so it's readable..

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: This thing is all fixed pixel widths & heights...It's not going to be responsive anyway. Don't position all the minor elements separately, wrap them in a div and position that...if you must.

Comment: My background image, now, is responsive, but words like "LIAM" don't follow X,Y position of LIAM (image)

Comment: Your "question" does not have a single question-mark in it

Answer (score 0):

instead of positioning each element individually , i suggest you give `position:absolute` to `#block1` and position it on the image ( image as background to `#container` or make another div surrounding the `#block1` div ) .

i used `top:40vh` -> `vh=viewport height`

and then position the elements inside the `block1` as you desire.

also i deleted the `#link` div and added styles directly to the link instead. seems more logical this way  :) . if you want a `link` to behave like a `div` use `display:block` , in this case i used `display:inline-block`

VERY IMPORTANT : do not use fixed `width` and `height` if you want something to be responsive. i used `width:100vw` on `.container` so it has the width of the screen.

see snippet below or fiddle here > **[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb1v1nae/2/)**

let me know if it works for you

```css
#container {
    background-image: url('http://tiffosi.com/fw16/img/img1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 1450px;
    max-width: 1086px;
    max-height: 1450px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  #block1 #title {
    font-family: oswald-bold;
    font-size: 60pt;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
  }

  #block1 #subtitle {
    font-family: oswald-bold;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }

  #block1  a{
    width: 184px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 43px;
    line-height: 43px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-family: Oswald-Medium;
    font-size: 11pt;
     color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:50px;
  }

  

  
  #block1 { 
  position:absolute;
  top:40vh;
  left:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="block1">
        <div id="title">LIAM</div>
        <div id="subtitle">SUPER SLIM FIT</div>
        <a href="#"> See all jeans</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Text don't follow top position, when i resize browser. Vertically, text are in the same position.

Comment: if you resize the browser only as width of course the text stays in the same poisition. it stays depending on the viewport height, if you want it to stay depending on the viewport width, use `vw` instead of `vh` . if you use percent it will stay depending on the height of the container, which you made it a fixed height  `height: 1450px;`